# Paypal Log In Button integration in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, paypal

I generated the code snippet for the LoginPaypal button from [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/identity/button-js-builder/) and it produced something like this:

```
<span id="paypalButton"></span>
<script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/js/external/api.js"></script>
<script>
    paypal.use( ["login"], function(login) {
      login.render ({
        "appid": <appid>,
        "authend": "sandbox",
        "scopes": "profile email address phone https://uri.paypal.com/services/paypalattributes",
        "containerid": "paypalButton",
        "locale": "en-us",
        "returnurl": "http://my.domain.here/return.php"
      });
    });
</script>
```

My app is an AngularJS app, and integrating this snippet it throws this error in the browsers console:

```
ReferenceError: paypal is not defined
at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/meritwork/assets/javascript/library/jquery.js:330:5), <anonymous>:1:1)
at eval (native)
at Function.jQuery.extend.globalEval (http://localhost:8080/meritwork/assets/javascript/library/jquery.js:330:5)
at jQuery.fn.extend.domManip (http://localhost:8080/meritwork/assets/javascript/library/jquery.js:5411:16)
at jQuery.fn.extend.append (http://localhost:8080/meritwork/assets/javascript/library/jquery.js:5194:15)
at null.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/meritwork/assets/javascript/library/jquery.js:5309:18)
at jQuery.access (http://localhost:8080/meritwork/assets/javascript/library/jquery.js:3465:8)
at jQuery.fn.extend.html (http://localhost:8080/meritwork/assets/javascript/library/jquery.js:5276:10)
at removePatch [as html] (http://localhost:8080/meritwork/assets/javascript/library/angular.js:2292:25)
at link (http://localhost:8080/meritwork/assets/javascript/library/angular-route.min.js:7:180) <div ng-view="" style="padding-top: 70px" class="ng-scope">
```

I am new to this field and I don't quite understand the error. I tried looking it up and didn't find anything. Does anyone have any suggestions of what it might be wrong ?

Thank you.

Comment: Need more info, where is your code snippet being rendered? Within an angular template?

Comment: Yes, the code snippet is inside an angular template.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The problem was that the js needed for paypal needed jquery and the jquery was loading after the paypal js. Moved the script inclusion after the jquery and all went well.